# open all html files in a directory in multiple browser types

Tags: batch-file, cross-browser, browser

I'm trying to test a html file in all browsers. Is there a way using the command line to open all of the .html files in a directory in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, etc. to ensure that the html files are working properly across all internet browsers?

This was my attempt at creating a .bat file to do so:

```
@echo off
set /p var= %%f
start "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" %var%
start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %var%
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" %var%
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "C:\pathtohtmlfiles"
for %%a in (*.htm *.html) do (
 start "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "file://%CD%\%%a"
 start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "%%a"
 start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%%a"
)
popd
```

Tested with IE 10, Chrome 31.0.1650.63 and FF 26.0

Comment: This works great, but it Google opens each file in a separate tab, while IE and FireFox open each in a separate window. Is there a way for IE and Firefox to open the files in different tabs instead of windows (Like Google does it)?